# Jquery slide div up from bottom of page

Tags: jquery, html, css

So far, I have a div fixed to the bottom of the page, with the bottom margin set to a minus number, so as to hide most of it below the screen. I'd like to create a Jquery button that made it all slide up onto the page, but everything I have tried so far hasn't worked. I'm not so experienced with it, so I've probably been doing it worng.

Anyway, here's my CSS:

```
.foot {
    border-top: 1px solid #999999;
    position:fixed;
    width: 600px;
    z-index: 10000;
    text-align:center;
    height: 500px;
    font-size:18px;
    color: #000;
    background: #FFF;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    border-top-left-radius:25px;
    border-top-right-radius:25px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    bottom: -475px;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="foot">
Copyright 2014 &copy; Tom Gibbs web design. <div class="clocker">hi</div>
<br />
<br />
Line 1<br />
Line 2<br />
Line 3<br />
Line 4
</div>
```

Code I already tried. It just made the div slide down off the page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".clocker").click(function(){
    $(".foot").slideUp(2000);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where is _Jquery_ code?

Comment: Like I said, I couldn't get anything remotely close, but I added the code I already tried in an edit

Comment: That was the only Jquery I tried so far. The rest were all CSS tricks that worked, but not very well. I'd rather use Jquery anyway

Comment: @user3779981 Instead of sliding up to reveal the rest of the content within the footer, wouldn't it work better if there was a separate container/modal that would slide up? This way, you can leave the footer alone and slide the other container/modal up as needed.

Comment: Well, right now, I'm working on using the addClass function to add a class that removes the bottom margin on click. It works, but I can't get it to go back down again

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What if you had another class:

```
.slide-up
{
    bottom: 0px !important;
}

.slide-down
{
    bottom: -475px !important;
}
```

which you could add on click:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.foot').click(function() {
      if($('.foot').hasClass('slide-up')) {
        $('.foot').addClass('slide-down', 1000, 'easeOutBounce');
        $('.foot').removeClass('slide-up'); 
      } else {
        $('.foot').removeClass('slide-down');
        $('.foot').addClass('slide-up', 1000, 'easeOutBounce'); 
      }
  });
});
```

Make sure you have jQuery UI imported first.

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/senju/qedz05v4/)

Comment: That does work pretty well, thanks. Would it be difficult to get it to go down again if the user clicks again?

Comment: @user3779981 Sure, fixed. Also, you can mess around with jQuery UI's different easing types, not just the bounce one

Comment: I really did like the bounce effect. I've not actually used these Jquery UI effects before, but I sure am going to now!

Comment: More shorter and $(function() {
    $('#dev-module-toolbar').click(function() {
       if($(this).hasClass('slide-up')) {
         $(this).toggleClass('slide-down', 'slide-up');
       } else {
         $(this).toggleClass('slide-up', 'slide-down');
       }
    });
    });

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is something you want: [<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/ys26nh7q/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".clocker").click(function(){
      $(".foot").animate({bottom:'300px'},1000);
  });
});
```

I have made some changes in your Css also:

```
.foot {
    border-top: 1px solid #999999;
    position:fixed;
    width: 600px;
    z-index: 10000;
    text-align:center;
    /*height: 500px;*/
    font-size:18px;
    color: #000;
    background: #FFF;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    border-top-left-radius:25px;
    border-top-right-radius:25px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

### Update

If you want to close it also **[See Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/ys26nh7q/2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".clocker").click(function(){
      if($(".foot").css('bottom') == '0px'){
          $(".foot").animate({bottom:'300px'},1000);
      }
      else
      {
          $(".foot").animate({bottom:'0px'},1000);
      }

  });
});
```

Comment: Your original demo could do with a `<button class='clocker'>Click</button>` in the html ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tris worked for me (coy and paste that in your code editor):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Slide Up</title>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>

        <style type="text/css">
            .container {
                position: absolute;
                top:0px;
                left:0px;
                bottom:0px;
                right:0px;
                width:80%;
                height:600px;
                border:1px solid black;
                margin:auto;
            }

            .menuB{
                position:absolute;
                width:100%;
                height:0;
                left:0;
                bottom:0;
                /*transform-origin:100% 100%;*/
                background:#2196F3;
                opacity:0;
                overflow:hidden;
            }

            .clickMe{
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: 0;
                right: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 30px;
                background-color: #2196F3;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>
        <body>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="menuB">

                </div>

                <p class="clickMe">Click</p>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                    var opacity_status = false;
                $('.clickMe').on('click', function () {
                    // body...
                    if (opacity_status === false) {
                        $('.menuB')
                           .animate({
                               opacity: 1
                           }, 100)
                           .animate({
                               height: '250px'
                           }, 1500 );
                        opacity_status = true;
                    }else{
                        $('.menuB')
                           .animate({
                              height : 0
                           }, 1500)
                           .animate({
                               opacity: 0
                           }, 2000 );
                        opacity_status = false;
                    }

                });
            </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late but I hope it will help somebody else.
I've made this discovery completely by fluke so I take no credit for it, nor do I really understand it. Perhaps its a bug.

I was able to use the `slideDown()` method and change the direction that my context menu slides simply by changing the css absolute top/bottom property to:`top: 0;` or `bottom: 0;`, depending on which way I wanted to go.

There's also a js fiddle: [Slide up or down polarity](https://jsfiddle.net/2pn8h7r6/16/)

```js
$('.option').click(function(evObject) {

  $("#contextContainer").slideDown(2500);
});
```

```css
#contextContainer {
  display: none;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 90%;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="controlContainer">
  <div class="option">Click me</div>
</div>

<div id="contextContainer">Context menu!!</div>
```