# slideDown from bottom to top (and not from top to bottom)

Tags: jquery, slide

I want to first hide a div and then show it building from bottom to top. I have seen that jQuery has a nice

```
.slideDown()
```

effect, however, the direction this transition is using is the opposite of what I need (it always begins showing the element from top). I kind of want to build a "tower" of divs in the end, to give you a mental image of what I'm trying to achieve.

How can what I want be solved using jQuery? I have already tried various things but didnt get it to work! Note that the height of the div is UNKNOWN as it is calculated on the fly (in theory I know the height of the div right when I reveal it).

*Note that the div does not have a fixed or absolute position. Also, multiple of these divs are stacked above each other. They get revealed from bottom to top.*

Links: http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery slide div up from bottom of page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174144/jquery-slide-div-up-from-bottom-of-page)

Comment: @MartinHučko thanks that looks good! Not as easy as I thought

Comment: @MartinHučko Okay that solution is not usable for my problem. My div does not have a **fixed position** like the one linked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried this with following code:

`HTML:`

```
<div style="height:200px; width: 200px; background-color: red;">
<span style="color:#fff">Click here</span>
</div>
```

`JQuery:`

```
$("div").click(function () {
      $(this).hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 1000);
      //direction: up,down
});
```

Check out this fiddle link for more .. [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/adminsunil/8tocgoyw/)

Hope it helps you...

Happy coding.. :)

Comment: What you posted **hides** the div from bottom to top. What I need is that the div **shows** from bottom to top. I've tried editing your code by making it hide first and then show using your method, but that only leads to the default slideDown() function which is exactly what I don't want.

Comment: Hopefully my efforts are solved your problem, Please do let me know if you are still facing  any issue in this ! Thanks Cheers :)

Comment: I got it working thanks to your new links, thanks. Unfortunately I have to include the entire jQuery UI librarby to achieve this effect...

Comment: That's greatjonas.. please mark my answer if it helpful to you thanks :)